# Is there a way to use 64-bit DLLs in the [Code] section in Inno Setup?

Tags: dll, 64-bit, inno-setup, 32bit-64bit, pascalscript

In the documentation [64-bit Installation Limitations](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_64bitlimitations.htm) the following is said:

> You cannot load/use 64-bit DLLs in the `[Code]` section, because Windows does not allow 32-bit processes to load 64-bit DLLs (and vice versa). A 32-bit process can, however, launch 64-bit EXEs. Use the Exec function or the `[Run]` section to do that.

Here [LoadDLL](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_loaddll.htm) it is said that `LoadDLL` function is deprecated and there's a link to [Using DLLs and .NET assemblies](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptdll.htm) instead. But there's nothing about bitness or `LoadDLL` function in here. Why would I need to use the `LoadDLL` function anyway and is there a way to use 64-bit DLLs in my `[Code]` section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno Setup is 32-bit, so it can load 32-bit DLLs only. The bitness of the system has no effect here. The [documentation you quote](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=64bitlimitations) is correct and absolutely clear:

> You cannot load/use 64-bit DLLs in the [Code] section, because Windows does not allow 32-bit processes to load 64-bit DLLs (and vice versa).

---

*That does not mean there's no solution for your specific problem, which you are trying to solve by loading the 64-bit DLL. But you have to ask about that specific problem.*

---

Note that Inno Setup can *register* 64-bit DLLs, as they are registered using an external process `regsvr32`, not by Inno Setup 32-bit process itself. There's 32-bit and 64-bit version of `regsvr32`. I believe you need to (and Inno Setup does that) to execute the right version of `regsvr32` according to the bitness of your DLL.